# Where did the Jamendo/Magnatune plugins go in Rhythmbox?

Tags: 11.10, rhythmbox

I used to love listening to Jamendo/Magnatune via Rhythmbox and it seemed they used to be included in the rhythmbox-plugins package, however the plugins do not appear in the plugins list and I can't find anything online saying they were removed or what not.

When I type in "Rhythmbox jamendo" in the software center it pops up the plugins package, yet still nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Magnatune plugin caused Rhythmbox to crash in 11.10, so it was disabled [[source]](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=661957#c2). The issue should be fixed in the development version which, as far as I can find, is only available in 12.04.

The Jamendo plugin has been discontinued [[source]](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=654637#c2).

Comment: Hi can I have an update on this?

Comment: @Andres I'm afraid I no longer use Rhythmbox or Magnatune, so I haven't kept myself up to date on this matter. If it still doesn't work, I would guess nothing has changed.

Comment: @Andres It works in Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing, then I went to Rhythmbox menu -> Plugins, checked "Magnatune", and it's there! Looks like it's installed, but not activated by default for some reason.